# Exchange 2010 and ESE Backup API

Tags: backup, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Exchange 2010 does not support the ESE API for doing backups like it did in 2003 and 2007 according to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876874.aspx). I Quote: "Exchange 2010 no longer supports the ESE streaming APIs for backup and restore of program files or data. Instead, Exchange 2010 supports only VSS-based backups."

So my question is, if this is the case, why is the DLL (ESEBCLI2.DLL) still shipped with exchange 2010? I found it under C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The High Availability component of Exchange 2010 uses some parts of the streaming backup API under the covers - for doing reseeds for example. The full API isn't supported though.

Comment: Ah. thankyou! Good to get an answer directly from MS. This question was pending for a while.